# Accessible fake checkbox with link in label

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

I'm trying to make a fake checkbox accessible. I have this markup:

```
<label role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" aria-labelledby="acceptedAgreementLabel" tabindex="0" >
    <span><!-- FAKE CHECKBOX ICON --></span>
    <span id="acceptedAgreementLabel">Jag bekräftar att jag tagit del av och godkänt 
        <a target="_blank" href="/anvandarvillkor">användarvillkoren</a> för Vinos.
    </span>
</label>
```

How ever, when trying this with VoiceOver, it skips the checkbox and only stops at the link inside the description. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also keep in mind the second rule of ARIA use (https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#secondrule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're effectively trying to make the input element and the label element into one thing, and that will almost certainly have unpredictable results. This is why it's so important to follow established standards in accessibility.

It's great that you're using Voiceover for testing, but the results of what you're doing here may be very unpredictable in other screen-reader/browser configurations. Furthermore, the behavior that you get today may change with product updates.

If there's some reason, you can't use a real input element for your checkbox, then consider using a generic div with the checkbox role instead of what you're doing here.

- [MDN Web Docs -- ARIA checkbox role documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/checkbox_role)
- [W3C Form Labeling Controls -- Implicit Labeling of HTML Inputs](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#associating-labels-implicitly)

Comment: Yes I agree it’s stupid to recreate perfectly working elements, but designers... I’ll try to use a div instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of label try to use anchor tag it will work as expected